# polymer, 'Computed' property not working in IE

Tags: polymer

why do not working in ie?

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#computed-properties

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">


<polymer-element name="square-element" attributes="square">
<template>
    <input type="number" value="{{num}}"><br>
    <em>{{num}}^2 = {{square}}</em>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('square-element', {
    num: 2,
    computed: {
    square: 'num * num'
    }
});
</script>
```

i tested in ie10, ie11...
..
but  good in chrome

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Webcomponents specifications are not yet included in all browsers. Some browsers needs polyfills in order to provide polymer features.
The polyfills are here:

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs

If you want to know what is implemented in each browser then monitor this page:

http://jonrimmer.github.io/are-we-componentized-yet/